# can anyone tell me whats wrong with this code

Tags: javascript, html

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
var userChoice=prompt("rock, paper or scissors ??");
var pcChoice=Math.random();
console.log(pcChoice);
if(pcChoice<=0.33){
    pcChoice="rock";
}
else if(pcChoice>=0.34 && pcChoice<=0.66){
    pcChoice="paper";
}
else{
    pcChoice="scissors";
}

var compare=function(choice1,choice2){
if(choice1=choice2){
    alert("it's a tie");
}
else if(choice1==="rock"){
    if(choice2==="scissors"){
        alert("rock wins");
    }
    else{
    alert("paper wins");
    }
}
else if(choice1===="paper"){
    if(choice2==="rock"){
        alert("paper wins");
    }
    else{
        alert("scissors wins");
    }
}
    else if(choice1===="scissors"){
    if(choice2==="paper"){
        alert("scissors wins");
    }
    else{
        alert("rock wins");
    }
}

}
compare(userChoice,pcChoice);
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

this is an easy rock paper scissors game
i opened the page but the javascript didnt start the alert boxes, it means theres something wrong with my code
please any help will be great
im a beginner at javascript but i have great knowledge in html and css(doesnt help at all)
can you review this code and tell me the problem please

Comment: Developer's console will tell you what's wrong. `====` is not an operator btw

Comment: use `if(choice1==choice2)` instead of `if(choice1=choice2)`

Comment: i wouldn't call this a basic typo. OP is clearly having problems with `=` operators as he used them consistantly false.

Comment: it is a typo, because i was using notepad++, it connects =

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is no such operator as `====` you need to fix them and it works. ah also you have `=` in if condition which ALWAYS returns true check the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BTRJL/1/):

```
var userChoice=prompt("rock, paper or scissors ??");
var pcChoice=Math.random();
console.log(pcChoice);
if(pcChoice<=0.33){
    pcChoice="rock";
}
else if(pcChoice>=0.34 && pcChoice<=0.66){
    pcChoice="paper";
}
else{
    pcChoice="scissors";
}

var compare=function(choice1,choice2){
if(choice1==choice2){
    alert("it's a tie");
}
else if(choice1==="rock"){
    if(choice2==="scissors"){
        alert("rock wins");
    }
    else{
    alert("paper wins");
    }
}
else if(choice1==="paper"){
    if(choice2==="rock"){
        alert("paper wins");
    }
    else{
        alert("scissors wins");
    }
}
    else if(choice1==="scissors"){
    if(choice2==="paper"){
        alert("scissors wins");
    }
    else{
        alert("rock wins");
    }
}

}
compare(userChoice,pcChoice);
```

Comment: i must have added an = i use notepad++ they look attached :P

Comment: also don't forget the `if(choice1==choice2){` part. in your code its always a tie.

Answer (score 1):

Make choice1 === choice2 in the first if statement.

Comment: its already said by u_mulder

Comment: @SumanBogati its commented but not answered

Comment: you meant not answered?

Comment: @SumanBogati yes some people like to put answers into comments rather than posting it as an answer...

Answer (score 1):

I have modified your script to this. Please try with this

```
var userChoice=prompt("rock, paper or scissors ??");
var pcChoice=Math.random();
console.log(pcChoice);
if(pcChoice<=0.33){
    pcChoice="rock";
}
else if(pcChoice>=0.34 && pcChoice<=0.66){
    pcChoice="paper";
}
else{
    pcChoice="scissors";
}

var compare=function(choice1,choice2){
if(choice1==choice2){
    alert("it's a tie");
}
else if(choice1=="rock"){
    if(choice2=="scissors"){
        alert("rock wins");
    }
    else{
    alert("paper wins");
    }
}
else if(choice1=="paper"){
    if(choice2=="rock"){
        alert("paper wins");
    }
    else{
        alert("scissors wins");
    }
    }
    else if(choice1=="scissors"){
    if(choice2=="paper"){
        alert("scissors wins");
    }
    else{
        alert("rock wins");
    }
}

}
compare(userChoice,pcChoice);
```